# Filtering in Django ManyToMany relationships

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Imagine models Carrier, Data_plan, Voice_plan. Data plan and Voice plan contain Foreign Key (Carrier). Now, since some data plans are available only for certain voice plans, Data_plan model contains ManyToMany field (Voice_plan). However, that lists ALL voice plans of all carriers available (in Django admin). How do I filter voice plans of the same carrier?

```
class Carrier(models.Model):
   # bunch of attributes
   #...

class Voice_plan(models.Model):
   # bunch of attributes
   carrier = ForeignKey(Carrier)
   #...

class Data_plan(models.Model):
   ...
   carrier = ForeignKey(Carrier)
   # if not available for all voice plans
   for_voice_plans = ManyToManyField(Voice_plan) # should be for those voice plans that share the same carrier...
```

Comment: That kind of relationship is not allowed. You will have to create your own RelatedManager

Comment: clarification: what is not allowed is to pre-filter the M2M, except by custom Manager.

Comment: Do all carriers have a voice plan?

Comment: Luis, yup, you are right. Even though I did write several custom managers in this case I am a bit lost. Would appreciate any hints.